# Blackberry - get checked items from list with checkboxes

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, java-me, listfield

How can all  checked items from a list can be fetched?

I need to get all selected (checked) items from the list and populate a vector.

I am not getting all selected items, I am getting only the item on which current focus is.

I am implementing listfield with checkboxes as per the knowledgebase article.

If I use getSelection(), it is returning me the currently highlighted list row index, and not all that have been checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I undestood, sample is [How To - Create a ListField with check boxes](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800345/How_To_-_Create_a_ListField_with_check_boxes.html?nodeid=1165752&vernum=0)

Then you can add Vector to the class where ListFieldCallback is implemented:

```
private Vector _checkedData = new Vector();
public Vector getCheckedItems() {
        return _checkedData;
    }
```

and update drawListRow this way:

```
if (currentRow.isChecked())
{
    if( -1 ==_checkedData.indexOf(currentRow))
        _checkedData.addElement(currentRow);
    rowString.append(Characters.BALLOT_BOX_WITH_CHECK);
}
else
{
    if( -1 !=_checkedData.indexOf(currentRow))
        _checkedData.removeElement(currentRow);
    rowString.append(Characters.BALLOT_BOX);
}
```

---

If you would use VerticalFieldManager with custom CheckBoxField, you could iterate over all fields on screen (or any manager) and check if its' checkbox field, then take a value:

```
class List extends VerticalFieldManager {
...
    public Vector getCheckedItems() {
        Vector result = new Vector();
        for (int i = 0, cnt = getFieldCount(); i < cnt; i++) {
            Field field = getField(i);
            if (field instanceof CheckboxField) {
                CheckboxField checkboxField = (CheckboxField) field;
                if (checkboxField.isChecked())
                    result.addElement(checkboxField);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: how to select all items at a time  in a listfield when clicking on the button selectall.plz give ur suggestions if anyone have idea about htat.

Answer (score 0):

@sandhya-m

```
class List extends VerticalFieldManager {
...
    public void selectAll() {
        for (int i = 0, cnt = getFieldCount(); i < cnt; i++) {
                Field field = getField(i);
                if (field instanceof CheckboxField) {
                        CheckboxField checkboxField = (CheckboxField) field;
                        checkboxField.setChecked(true);
                }
        }
    }
}
```